# Remove SonataAdmin logo

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-3.4, symfony-sonata

I am trying to remove SonataAdmin logo. I don't want any picture. Every param that I put in my .yml file I get a broken picture icon on my admin view.

I have checked the conifguration and there is no wirtten documentation of how to hide logo.

```
   sonata_admin:
      templates:
          user_block: '@AdminTemplates/user_block.html.twig'
      title: My App
      title_logo: /bundles/sonataadmin/logo_title.png   //-- this part
```

Comment: delete / at the begin of  /bundles/sonataadmin/logo_title.png

Answer (score 1):

Put your logo file here

```
src/AppBundle/Resources/public/images/your_logo.png
```

install asset :

```
$ php bin/console assets:install
```

And I think you have just to delete the first slash / in the title_logo :

```
 # app/config/config.yml
 sonata_admin:
      templates:
          user_block: '@AdminTemplates/user_block.html.twig'
      title: My App
      title_logo: bundles/app/images/your_logo.png   //-- this part
```

The point here is to make a transparent image , so you can't see the logo, otherwise , there is no way to do it .

Comment: Thank you for replay. However, I tried this solution and it doesn't work. And I don't have any logo image. I just wan't for sonata logo to be removed. @MohammedYassineCHABLI

Comment: think to make a transparent image install instead

Comment: I did that and it removes the title in that case as well.. @MohammedYassineCHABLI

Comment: Maybe using css?